# Is there a php function to determine whether an array element has changed?

Tags: php, foreach

Within a foreach statement i want to see if a certain array element has changed or not.  If not, increment my counter.  If so, set back to one.  Is there an easy way to do this?   something like...

```
$position = 1; 

foreach( $rowDatas as $row )
{
    //insert $row into db;

    if( ! hasChanged($row[0]) )
    {
        $position = $postion + 1;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $position = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like you're generating the array from a database record? If so, just select the existing value and use a comparison operator before inserting the new one. Otherwise please elaborate on your question.

Comment: Im actually generating the array from an excel spreadsheet that is uploaded and inserting it into my db.  After i insert the first row i want to see if the first element in the next row is the same as the previous.  hope this helps.

Comment: Is each row of the Excel spreadsheet stored in the array `$rowDates`?

Comment: And does `$row[0]` represent a cell on that `$row`?

Comment: Yes, each row from the spreadsheet is stored in $rowDatas, and $row[0] within the foreach loop holds the contents of the first cell from each row.  (Ex. A1, A2, A3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any sort of function that would do what i wanted to so i created somewhat of a workaround.  $rowDatas[2][0]; is the first element I wanted to compare.

```
$position = 0;
$a = $rowDatas[2][0];


        try
        {

            foreach( $rowDatas as $row )
            {

                if( $row[0] == $a ){
                    $position++;
                }
                else {
                        $position = 1;
                        $a = $row[0];
                 }
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Sandbox (row0, row1, row2, Position) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
                    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(3, $row[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt->bindParam(4, $position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $status = $stmt->execute();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use array_diff if and only if you don't care about which item inside the row were modified.

```
$a = $rowDatas[2];

foreach( $rowDatas as $row ) {
    if (array_diff($a, $row)) {
        $position++;

        // ...
    } 
}
```